# Fetching the RGB image from kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using kinect sensor for the mapping and navigation in my project, As Kinect also have a RGB camera.
I wanted to fetch the RGB image from the kinect, then do some processing and get the text data in the image using this data I want to re localise my robot.

Is this possible in ros.?

Many Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191623/fetching-the-rgb-image-from-kinect/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure! just subscribe to the RGB image topic. Assuming you started the openni with

`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

Just subscribe to /camera/rgb/image_raw topic. The sensor_msgs/Image messages you get can be easily converted to OpenCV with cv_bridge package.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-02**:
oh thanks, any already available packages for text extraction from images.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-09-02**:
Dear @sumanth, if this answer is satisfactory for you, please, mark it as correct. Also, it would be more appropriate to ask about the package for text extraction from images as a new question, as it could be helpful for other people. Thank you for helping us keep the forum organised.